# How to play amazon S3 videos in wordpress 3.6?

Tags: videos, amazon

The latest release of WP has its own media player (mediaelement.js), to include and play a video we no more need a separate media player now. My question is

How can I make the `[video]` shortcode work with videos uploaded on S3 which are protected.

I try using this

```
[video mp4="http://xyz.s3.amazonaws.com/test.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIFXXXXXXG7A7A&Expires=1375464588&Signature=ZimqpfuYZQwQIrPaVnodi4WASO0%3D"]
```

But that doesn't seem to work. The URL I created has expire time of 300s, if I try to run the test.mp4 in a new tab,  it works. But it doesn't play in wordpress.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried putting the URL of the MP4 on a line of its own OEmbed style like Youtube?

Comment: But OEmbed doesn't work for S3 I think. You meant among the list http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds right?

Comment: I found out something using [video mp4] shortcode the url should end with a .mp4 extension or else it won't work, now in the case above, what I have is expiring URLs which doesn't have extensions at the end. What can be done about this?